# Test Services not working with DispatcherHelper in Windows 8.1 mvvm light app

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-8.1, mvvm-light, dispatcher

I have a bunch of methods to load data in my Windows 8.1 Runtime App.  I am using MVVM Light 5.1.1.0.

I have been struggling for a while now to figure out why the sample, stock, project has working test services and why I could never get mine to work.  Turns out that if I remove ALL of my DispatcherHelper calls, then my test data loads.

Here is an example of one of many things I call in my View Model's Load method:

```
    private async Task LoadDriverStatuses()
    {
        var driverStatuses = await this._driverService.GetDriverStatuses();

        this.DriverStatuses = new ObservableCollection<DriverStatusVM>();

        foreach (var status in driverStatuses)
        {
            var driverStatusVM = new DriverStatusVM
            {
                DriverStatusId = status.Id,
                Name = status.Name
            };
            await DispatcherHelper.RunAsync(() =>
            {
                this.DriverStatuses.Add(driverStatusVM);
            });
        }
    }
```

If I comment out the DispatcherHelper.RunAsync()/CheckBeginInvokeOnUI() line everywhere in the view model, my test data will load in the designer.  Unfortunately, the application only fully loads everything once, correctly.  as soon as I try to, say, change the drivers status then I get a 'marshalled thread access error'.  This is because all of these lists are created on separate threads.

I am wondering if there is a quick way to fix this, or if I need to proceed with a 'if(this.IsInDesignMode)' block in my view models constructor and rip out all DispatcherHelper.